# How to extract chains from a PDB file?

Tags: python, bash, bioinformatics, biopython

I would like to extract chains from pdb files. I have a file named pdb.txt which contains pdb IDs as shown below. The first four characters represent PDB IDs and  last character is the chain IDs.

```
1B68A 
1BZ4B
4FUTA
```

I would like to  1) read the file line by line 
                 2) download the atomic coordinates of each chain from the corresponding PDB files.
                 3) save the output to a folder.

I used the following script to extract chains. But this code prints only A chains from pdb files.

```
for i in 1B68 1BZ4 4FUT
do 
wget -c "http://www.pdb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId="$i -O $i.pdb
grep  ATOM $i.pdb | grep 'A' > $i\_A.pdb
done
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following BioPython code should suit your needs well.

It uses `PDB.Select` to only select the desired chains (in your case, one chain) and `PDBIO()` to create a structure containing just the chain.

```
import os
from Bio import PDB


class ChainSplitter:
    def __init__(self, out_dir=None):
        """ Create parsing and writing objects, specify output directory. """
        self.parser = PDB.PDBParser()
        self.writer = PDB.PDBIO()
        if out_dir is None:
            out_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chain_PDBs")
        self.out_dir = out_dir

    def make_pdb(self, pdb_path, chain_letters, overwrite=False, struct=None):
        """ Create a new PDB file containing only the specified chains.

        Returns the path to the created file.

        :param pdb_path: full path to the crystal structure
        :param chain_letters: iterable of chain characters (case insensitive)
        :param overwrite: write over the output file if it exists
        """
        chain_letters = [chain.upper() for chain in chain_letters]

        # Input/output files
        (pdb_dir, pdb_fn) = os.path.split(pdb_path)
        pdb_id = pdb_fn[3:7]
        out_name = "pdb%s_%s.ent" % (pdb_id, "".join(chain_letters))
        out_path = os.path.join(self.out_dir, out_name)
        print "OUT PATH:",out_path
        plural = "s" if (len(chain_letters) > 1) else ""  # for printing

        # Skip PDB generation if the file already exists
        if (not overwrite) and (os.path.isfile(out_path)):
            print("Chain%s %s of '%s' already extracted to '%s'." %
                    (plural, ", ".join(chain_letters), pdb_id, out_name))
            return out_path

        print("Extracting chain%s %s from %s..." % (plural,
                ", ".join(chain_letters), pdb_fn))

        # Get structure, write new file with only given chains
        if struct is None:
            struct = self.parser.get_structure(pdb_id, pdb_path)
        self.writer.set_structure(struct)
        self.writer.save(out_path, select=SelectChains(chain_letters))

        return out_path


class SelectChains(PDB.Select):
    """ Only accept the specified chains when saving. """
    def __init__(self, chain_letters):
        self.chain_letters = chain_letters

    def accept_chain(self, chain):
        return (chain.get_id() in self.chain_letters)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ Parses PDB id's desired chains, and creates new PDB structures. """
    import sys
    if not len(sys.argv) == 2:
        print "Usage: $ python %s 'pdb.txt'" % __file__
        sys.exit()

    pdb_textfn = sys.argv[1]

    pdbList = PDB.PDBList()
    splitter = ChainSplitter("/home/steve/chain_pdbs")  # Change me.

    with open(pdb_textfn) as pdb_textfile:
        for line in pdb_textfile:
            pdb_id = line[:4].lower()
            chain = line[4]
            pdb_fn = pdbList.retrieve_pdb_file(pdb_id)
            splitter.make_pdb(pdb_fn, chain)
```

---

One final note: **don't write your own parser** for PDB files. The format specification is ugly (*really ugly*), and the amount of faulty PDB files out there is staggering. Use a tool like BioPython that will handle parsing for you!

Furthermore, instead of using `wget`, you should use tools that interact with the PDB database for you. They take FTP connection limitations into account, the changing nature of the PDB database, and more. I should know - I [updated `Bio.PDBList`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/7ebf6e9ecbebdf4fd093110f8d8eb218b02f6b1b) to account for changes in the database. =)

Comment: Thank you very much for your code and explanation. But I don't know, how to run your code? Could you help me?

Comment: Sure thing. I added a method that's specifically suited to your goals. Change the line in the main body to the directory you want your files to go to. [Install Python](http://www.python.org/getit/) (you probably already have it, try `$ which python`), and install [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Download#Installation_Instructions). Save the above file with a `.py` extension (e.g. `extract.py`), then run `$python extract.py pdb.txt`. That's it!

Comment: If you're doing more bioinformatics-related things, I highly suggest you learn Python. It's very popular in the field ([BioPython](http://biopython.org) and [PyMOL](http://pymol.org), are two good examples), and it's a good general language. The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org) and [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/) are both good places to start.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a little late for asnwering this question, but I will give my opinion.
[Biopython](http://biopython.org/) has some really handy features that would help you achieve such a think easily. You could use something like a custom selection class and then call it for each one of the chains you want to select inside a for loop with the original pdb file.

```
    from Bio.PDB import Select, PDBIO
    from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

    class ChainSelect(Select):
        def __init__(self, chain):
            self.chain = chain

        def accept_chain(self, chain):
            if chain.get_id() == self.chain:
                return 1
            else:          
                return 0

    chains = ['A','B','C']
    p = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)       
    structure = p.get_structure(pdb_file, pdb_file)

    for chain in chains:
        pdb_chain_file = 'pdb_file_chain_{}.pdb'.format(chain)                                 
        io_w_no_h = PDBIO()               
        io_w_no_h.set_structure(structure)
        io_w_no_h.save('{}'.format(pdb_chain_file), ChainSelect(chain))
```

Comment: How would you keep the secondary structures in the chain files?  This only gets the atoms from each chain and you loose the HELIX and SHEET annotations.

Comment: The only way I can think off is to extract that information from the *PDBParser* object using the **get_header()** method, and then add it to the file later on. This might help https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.PDB.PDBParser.html#Bio.PDB.PDBParser.PDBParser.get_header

Answer (score 1):

The accepted biopython solution seems to no longer work out of the box in 2023, but I found a simple R-based solution that worked for me and want to share for others who come across this post.

```
library(bio3d)
pdbsplit("pdb.txt", path = "split_chain")
```

This will split the file into one file per chain in the directory "split_chain". The [bio3d](http://thegrantlab.org/bio3d/reference/pdbsplit.html) package documentation includes more details.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Also seeing that the biopython solution isn't simple to get working in 2023 (now 2024).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the following file pdb_structures

```
1B68A 
1BZ4B
4FUTA
```

Then have your code in load_pdb.sh

```
while read name
do
    chain=${name:4:1}
    name=${name:0:4}
    wget -c "http://www.pdb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId="$name -O $name.pdb
    awk -v chain=$chain '$0~/^ATOM/ && substr($0,20,1)==chain {print}' $name.pdb > $name\_$chain.pdb
    #   rm $name.pdb
done
```

uncomment the last line if you don't need the original pdb's.
execute

```
cat pdb_structures | ./load_pdb.sh
```

Comment: This is simple and effective, but it ignores [HETATM](http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html#HETATM) records, which are part of a chain. Why write your own parser for a complex file format when there are plenty of already existing parsers?

Comment: Also, using a PDB-retrieval program is a much better option than using wget with a hand-retrieved URL. Compression is handled automatically, among other features. See the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @zelleke, Thank you very much for your answer.I tried your code. I don't need all chains from pdb files. I have mentioned the chain Id in the text file. for example, I need only 'A' chain from  '1B68'.